# SharePoint 2010 Search crawl rules - how to include only few BDC entities from external data Source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2010 Search Service Application is crawling all the BDC Entities in External data Source that is included in the BDC Service Application on the same farm. The problem I have is I don't want some of the entities in this namespace to show up in the Search results and also I have created Profile pages only for those few entities that I want to show up in the Search results.

Question is, Is there a way to select only these few entities to be crawled from this External Data Source or exclude others from the search result. I see only two options on the UI, either all External data Sources in the BDC Service Application or Selected External Data Source, what about ***Selected Entities in the Selected External Data Source***?  Any option to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out....
I needed to update the BDC model of the entities that I needed Search to crawl. 
Update the Finder methods to include these two properties 
   
          
          
   
If you don't want the entity to be Crawled by Search, don't include these properties to the finder method.